# turnjs steve jobs example - how to load first 4 pages

Tags: turnjs

I am new to turn.js and I am trying to modify the steve jobs book that comes with it.

The first 3 pages of the book are images and set in css like so

```
.sj-book .p1,
.sj-book .p2,
.sj-book .p3, 
.sj-book .p111, 
.sj-book .p112{
    background-color:white;
    background-image:url(../pics/book-covers.jpg) !important;
}
```

However I would like to load the first 4 pages as normal html pages like the other pages (e.g. page1.html). However the code only seems to start loading pages at page 5. If i add an alert to the missing function which loads the pages dynamically, the first page loaded is page 5

missing: function (e, pages) {

```
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
alert(pages[i]);
addPage(pages[i], $(this));}
```

}

When the books loads for the first time, this alert appears twice - for pages 5 and 6 -which sort of makes sense as the book only keeps 6 pages in memory - but why isn't the book loading pages 1 to 4? I have created the necessary html files for pages 1-4 in the pages directory but they are not loadded.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Ironically as soon as I post the question i find the answer - https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/306. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the Ref Link Indicate : https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/306

we need to perform the following steps

1) Remove following HTML (As re the static reference to pages )

```
<div depth="5" class="hard">
      <div class="side"></div>
</div>

<div depth="5" class="hard front-side">
      <div class="depth"></div>
</div>

<div class="own-size"></div>    
<div class="own-size even"></div>
```

2) remove respective CSS as address in ques

```
.sj-book .p1,
.sj-book .p2,
.sj-book .p3, 
.sj-book .p111, 
.sj-book .p112{
    background-color:white;
    background-image:url(../pics/book-covers.jpg) !important;
}
```

3) copy respective pages to pages folder with the name
Page1.html
Page2.html
and so on..